# github actions - check run, can i trigger a job with multiple conditions?

Tags: github-actions, github-check-run

Can I use `check_run` trigger in Github Actions the following way?

```
  on:
     check_run:
       types: [completed]
       conclusion: [success]
       name: [mytest]
```

Is there anyone who can give me a correct example to follow?

Comment: According to the [`check_run` trigger documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#check_run) there is only one subtype in this trigger which is the `type` field.

Comment: You could use a job-level if-condition for other fields.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts i check all the context, there is no conditions to get the result, like the ${{github.ref}} ?